# 2nd Page not showing up?

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my code :

```
import sys
from tkinter import *


#first new screen
def next_screen(names):
    for widget in names:
        widget.place_forget()
        buttonhyp = Button (text = "button1",fg = "blue",command = hypoténusegetdef())
        buttonhyp.grid (row = 1,column = 2)

def forget_page1():
    widgets = [mLabel1, button]
    next_screen(widgets)

################################################################################

def hypténusegetdef ():
    widgets1 = [buttonhyp]
    nextscreen1(widgets1)

def next_screen(names):
    for widget in names:
        widget.place_forget() 
        hyplabel1 = Label (text = "This is my text")








#first page things
mGui = Tk ()

mGui.geometry("600x600+545+170")
mGui.title("MyMathDictionary")
mLabel1 = Label (text = "Welcome to MyMathDictionary. Press Next to continue.",
                 fg = "blue",bg = "white")
mLabel1.place (x= 150,y = 200)

button = Button (text = "Next", command = forget_page1 )
button.place(x = 275,y = 230)




mGui.mainloop()
```

What i'm trying to do is to open the program and get the user to click on "Next" and then to show another button which is called "button1" and when the user clicks on "button1" it shows up a text called which says "This is my text" in my code.But when i run it i click on "Next" and nothing shows up i checked and re- checked but nothing seems to work.Any help would be appreciated.

#

Comment: And in the next_screen function i removed the () from hypotenusegetdef :)....

Comment: which one? you have two!!! only the second is considered by the program. please correct the code and show what is the output you get. As it is this code can not work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but i will give it a try.

Firstly, `import sys` is not necessary. And importing all the objects from tkinter module using `from tkinter import*` is not recommended. You should use `import tkinter` or `import tkinter as tk` to avoid unexepcted consequences.

You have 2 functions with the same name. `next_screen(names)` which should not happen.

Instead of using `widgets = [mLabel1, button]` to hide the widgets, you should put them in a frame so that you can use `winfo_children()` to find all the children widgets.

You should put the `parent widget name` when you create buttons and labels. for example,

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
mylabel = tk.Label(root,text='this is a label')
mylabel.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In your first `next_screen(names)` function , you used `grid method` to display the button. You should not mix the `grid method` and `place method`.

This is something i came up with

```
import tkinter as tk

def Screen_1():
    Clear(myframe) 
    mybutton2= tk.Button(myframe,text = "Button1", command = Screen_2)
    mybutton2.pack()

def Screen_2():
    Clear(myframe)
    mylabel2= tk.Label(myframe,text = "This is my text",fg = "blue",bg = "white")
    mylabel2.pack(side='top')

def Clear(parent):
    for widget in parent.winfo_children():
        widget.pack_forget()

root =tk.Tk()

myframe=tk.Frame(root)
myframe.pack()

mylabel1= tk.Label(myframe,text = "Welcome to MyMathDictionary. Press Next to continue.",fg = "blue",bg = "white")
mylabel1.pack(side='top')

mybutton1= tk.Button(myframe,text = "Next", command = Screen_1)
mybutton1.pack(side='bottom')

root.mainloop()
```

hope it helps!

Comment: re "You should not use grid method to display just 1 item.": Why do you say that? There's nothing wrong with using grid for one item, though `pack` is generally more convenient in that situation. Otherwise, good job pointing out all the flaws.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have removed the line you pointed out. I always thought grid manager is for table like structures. It doesn't seem logical (at least to me) to use `rows and columns` when you only have one item. But i have started learning Tkinter like only several months ago, so i might be wrong.